# Settings xorg.conf to be used with VESA driver?

Tags: xorg, 9.10

I have an brand new installation of Ubuntu 9.10 (karmic version) where everything is fine except the video resolution. In Ubuntu 9.10, the file xorg.conf is empty by default.

I'm using an onboard video card, and Ubuntu can not find the right resolution for me. It always uses 800x600, but I need at least 1024x768. Also, my monitor is listed as Unknown Type.

Ubuntu did find the right resolution when I changed the monitor to a Samsung monitor.

By the way what are the generic settings to put inside xorg.conf?

What is the settings for Refresh Rate, for example, I got a resolution of 1280x800, but the Refresh Rate generally between 60 ~ 80 htz is ZERO on my resolution..
In 1024 resolution my Refresh Rate is 75 htz..

What is going on with my resolution and how to modify the Refresh Rate??

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would not install 9.10 (karmic) especially not as "brand new  installation" since its support ends within about two months: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Release_history

Second: modern Xorg releases have the goal to work without any configuration file, just run-time detection is enough in *most* cases. Sure, if there is /etc/X11/xorg.conf it will be used still. You can generate one with `Xorg -configure` command (as root, of course from a text VT, not from running X), and you may modify it a bit later then, if you need to customize it. As far as I remember that command will generate the config file in your home with name like xorg.conf.new, so you need to move it to the right place too.

Comment: sorry about "brand new installation" hahaha ... but  I just picked up the first linux I saw in my case and did the installation.. and Unfortunattley the ubuntu do not recognize my video monitor, then I gave a command sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf and Added some lines in there, and everything okay, but the Refresh rate shows to me as 0 (ZERO) in a resolution of 1280x800, when I get back to 1024x768 all is fine, Refresh rate change to 75 hzt.. Do you have any idea why is it happening?

Comment: What is odd for me: why do you want to use the VESA driver? Isn't your card supported at all just with vesa? What kind of hardware it, exactly? (you can use `lspci` command to get information about devices on the PCI & related bus)

Comment: it is an onboard driver, a generic driver VESA. It is an old PC with intel celeron Processor and onboard drivers. I still have the problem with the Refresh Rate of my monitor.. it should be something between 40 - 60 Hz and never up to 75 Hz ... and can not solve this issue.. any idea?